# Where to catch exceptions when using Task.ContinueWith?

Tags: exception, async-await

I would like to create an async method with Task that creates a file and immediately proceeds to executing next task which uploads created file to cloud.
Here is how this method looks:

```
public async TaskCreateAndUploadAsync()
{
     await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {                 
                var _writeFile = new WriteFile(...);
                _writeFile.DoWork();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Log..
            }
        }).ContinueWith((result) =>
        {
        if (!result.IsFaulted)
            {
            try
            {
               storage.UploadCreatedObject(...);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Log..
            }
          }
        });
}
```

My question is: Is the way how I catch exceptions in each Task individually correct or I should use one try-catch block around whole "Task..Task.ContinueWith"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where to catch exceptions when using Task.ContinueWith?

The proper answer is "don't use `ContinueWith`". For asynchronous code, you can use `await` instead; for synchronous code like this, you can just use nothing:

```
public async TaskCreateAndUploadAsync()
{
  await Task.Run(async () =>
  {
    try
    {                 
      var _writeFile = new WriteFile(...);
      _writeFile.DoWork();
      storage.UploadCreatedObject(...);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      //Log..
    }
  });
}
```

However, [wrapping a method body in `Task.Run` like this is an antipattern](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/); it's better to keep the method synchronous and have *callers* use `Task.Run`:

```
public void TaskCreateAndUpload()
{
  try
  {                 
    var _writeFile = new WriteFile(...);
    _writeFile.DoWork();
    storage.UploadCreatedObject(...);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    //Log..
  }
}
```

From your method names, it sounds like some of them *should* be asynchronous. I/O is inherently asynchronous. So, if you have truly asynchronous I/O (i.e., not using `Task.Run` for fake-asynchrony), then your resulting method may look like this:

```
public async Task TaskCreateAndUploadAsync()
{
  try
  {                 
    var _writeFile = new WriteFile(...);
    await _writeFile.DoWorkAsync();
    await storage.UploadCreatedObjectAsync(...);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    //Log..
  }
}
```

Note the use of `await` instead of `ContiueWith` in this last example.

Comment: Thank you for answer. In my case _writeFile.DoWork() is not asynchronous and I do not have access to it to change that. UploadCreatedObject method can be made async, but if the first one is not, that doesn't make much difference. So I guess the way to go here is to use second code snippet and just make callers use Task.Run?

Comment: @niks: Yes, you'd need your callers to use `Task.Run`. You can also make `UploadCreatedObject` asynchronous, but your callers would still need to use `Task.Run`.

Comment: Thank you for help!